# FileZilla: How to get updated German time?

Tags: date-time, filezilla

I am using `FileZilla` for `FTP` and `SFTP` data server in Germany with FileZilla language English. When ever I am sending data or taking data from a server, I am getting time (last modified) which is almost `+2 hours` more than German time.

I tried to search somewhere in the setting, but didn't succeed.
[image: Pic]

Comment: What is your time-zone?

Comment: My time zone is Central European Summer Time. Time zone: (GMT+2)
Monday, 16 August 2021, 07:42

Comment: Check if the [date settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Sxj.png) are set to default. The image is from a windows PC, not sure if the settings are the same in Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the article
[3 Steps to Make Filezilla Preserve Timestamp](https://logic.edchen.org/3-steps-to-make-filezilla-preserve-timestamp/)
for details.

In a nutshell, you need In the Transfer menu of FileZilla to enable
"Preserve timestamps of transferred files".

If the problem is not on your side but at the server with the
[Server time offset](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org),
in this case in the Site Manager you have the option to negate
the wrong offset.

You may reach the Site Manager at the menu
*File > Site Manager > Advanced*, where you need to tweak
the value of "Adjust server timezone offset":

[image]

Comment: It seems that the timestamp *is preserved*, just is a wrong timezone.

Comment: Normally FileZilla should detect the timezone automatically, except if in the Site Manager the poster set an offset. Another possibility is that the FTP server might be configured wrongly, see : [Server time offset](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Server_time_offset). In this case in the Site Manager you have the option to negate the wrong offset.

Comment: I enabled  the "Preserve timestamps of transferred files", but still I am not getting updated time.

Comment: If the problem is with the server, you'll need to set a time offset in Site Manager for this server.

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me? Where is the Site Manager?

Comment: Added to my answer.